# 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2602' in position 438: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, utf-8

I am running into this problem where when I try to decode a string I run into one error,when I try to encode I run into another error,errors below,is there a permanent solution for this?

P.S please note that you may not be able to reproduce the encoding error with the string I provided as I couldnt copy/paste some errors

```
text =  "sometext"

string = '\n'.join(list(set(text)))
try:
    print "decode"
    text = string.decode('UTF-8')
except Exception as e:
    print e
    text = string.encode('UTF-8')
```

Errors:-

error while using string.decode('UTF-8')

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2602' in position 438: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Error while using string.encode('UTF-8')

```
Exception All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters
```

Comment: You should not be learning Python 2 in this day and age. Are you able to reproduce this with Python 3 (with the required changes to use `print()` etc)?

Comment: If you can print the `repr()` of the problematic string, you will see a representation which should be easy to copy/paste here.

Answer (score 0):

**The First Error**

The code you have provided will work as the text is a a bytestring (as you are using Python 2). But what you're trying to do is to decode from a UTF-8 string to 
an ASCII one, which is possible, but only if that Unicode string contains only characters that have an ASCII equivalent (you can see the list of ASCII characters [here](http://www.asciitable.com/)). In your case, it's encountering a unicode character (specifically ☂) which has no ASCII equivalent. You can get around this behaviour by using:

```
string.decode('UTF-8', 'ignore')
```

Which will just ignore (i.e. replace with nothing) the characters that cannot be encoded into ASCII.

**The Second Error**

This error is more interesting. It appears the text you are trying to *encode* into UTF-8 contains either NULL bytes or specific [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character), which are not allowed by the version of Unicode (UTF-8) that you are trying to encode into. Again, the code that you have actually provided works, but something in the text that you are trying to encode is violating the encoding. You can try the same trick as above:

```
string.encode('UTF-8', 'ignore')
```

Which will simply remove the offending characters, or you can look into what it is in your specific text input that is causing the problem.

Comment: This didn't help,even after adding `string.decode('UTF-8', 'ignore')` I get the same error

Comment: @user3508811 can you provide the string you're trying to decode and the version of python you're trying to achieve it in?